# The getter 'regular' isn't defined for the type 'PhosphorIcons'

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I have a problem in Flutter, Android Studio with the error:

The getter 'regular' isn't defined for the type 'PhosphorIcons'.

```
            leading: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
              child: Center(
                child: Icon(
                  PhosphorIcons.regular.image,
                  color: Colors.grey[500],
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What is `PhosphorIcons`? If that's a package. Please [edit] your question to include a link to it.

Comment: the way to get a regular probably has been changed... try downgrading package or using the new way...

Answer (score 0):

If your package is [phosphor_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/phosphor_flutter), then the API is changed to

```
PhosphorIconsRegular.image
```

API Reference here: [PhosphorIconsRegular](https://pub.dev/documentation/phosphor_flutter/latest/phosphor_flutter/PhosphorIconsRegular-class.html)